# Password management in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, hash, passwords, password-storage

I have some functions in my `.bashrc` file which are used to issue backup commands on remote websites. Right now, the username and password fields are stored as function-local strings in plain text within the function definition. Is there a better way of doing this?

My idea so far was to put a hashed version of the passwords in a file to which only my user account has read access, run a de-hashing command-line function on it and store the plain text result in memory, use it, then clear it.

Is there a better/safer or even a de-facto common way of accomplishing this?

Thank you.

Comment: If the remote sites are accessed with ssh/scp/rsync, then setting up ssh keys is the obvious way to go. At a minimum, change the permission on your .bashrc: `chmod 600 ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of safely approaching this problem.

### 1. GPG

Keep a GPG encrypted file with your passwords in it in `key=value` format (shell parsable basically), one per line. Such as:

```
foo_pass='bar'
pop_pass='tart'
```

When you want to access them, just do:

```
eval "$(gpg -d /path/to/file | grep '^foo_pass=')"
SUPERSECRETPASSWORD="$foo_pass" somecmd
```

If the command needs the password as an argument (this is unsafe), just adjust that last line.

### 2. Keyring daemon

Depending on your OS, you might have access to a keyring which you can store your passwords in. On linux, this might be the [gnome keyring daemon](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring). Then this keyring can probably be accessed via CLI/script somehow.
For example, there is [gkeyring](https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring) for use with the gnome keyring daemon.