# How to hide my password when I want to use 'nohup' command to excuate python script in background?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, click, nohup

I want to hide my password when excuating my script in the server. Because I share the server with others and I'm only a user. And the root of server can see my script. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
import click
username = click.prompt('username:')
password = click.prompt('password:', hide_input=True)
.....
```

When I use this code, it seems not to assign the input to username and password.

```
nohup python -u login.py
```

If I use this code, the root can use ps command to see my password.

```
nohup python -u login.py username password
ps aux|grep python      # the root can see my password using this code
```

Is there any way for me to solve this problem, thanks?

Comment: Would a better option be to set a user-specific environment variable with the password? It's not ideal, but better than typing out.

Comment: Could you please give me more details. I'm a tiro.

Comment: If the server uses bash shell you'll have a .bashrc file where you could add an environment variable. Slightly better than typing it on command line. It would just look like this: `export MY_PW=my_pw` for bash shell again. If you'd like to look into more secure options, here are a couple of ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322940/42346

Comment: OK, thanks a lot.